# Put images from Spine-js runtime to PSD

Tags: jsx, photoshop-script

My goal is assemble json + png files (spine animation) to PSD file like a layers using JSX.
A problem is current spine JS runtime has version 3.1.08 
and my json has been created by v 3.5.46! here is a lot of differences like a transformation, attachment type, etc.

is here a simple way to include some pixi or phaser spine libs or something else to take complete attachments positions?

now I am doing something like that:
I extend spine-canvas.js and add following code:

```
getImagesOptions: function() {        
    var skeleton = this.skeleton;
    var drawOrder = skeleton.drawOrder;
    var list = [];
    this.update();

    for (var i = 0, n = drawOrder.length; i < n; i++) {
        var slot = drawOrder[i];
        var attachment = slot.attachment;
        if (!(attachment instanceof spine.RegionAttachment)) continue;
        var bone = slot.bone;

          list.push( {
              x: attachment.x * bone.a + attachment.y * bone.b + bone.worldX + skeleton.x,
              y: attachment.x * bone.c + attachment.y * bone.d + bone.worldY + skeleton.y,
              w: attachment.width * bone.getWorldScaleX(),
              h: attachment.height * bone.getWorldScaleY(),
              r: (bone.getWorldRotationX() - attachment.rotation),
              a: attachment.rendererObject
        });
    }

    return list;
},
```

after init a spine just take a list of all images and move it to actual positions inside PSD layers. A question is where I can take actual spine runtime for use into JSX?
Thanks.